# Drupal 8 - Bootstrap paragraphs not rendering color and width classes

Tags: theming, 8, paragraphs

I have installed bootstrap paragraphs module and when setting the color and width to the "Simple" bundle or any default bundles that comes with "Bootstrap Paragraphs" the classes are not being rendered on the div.

Please see image below: The classes should have been added to the wrapping div.
[image]

This is how the source looks like for this paragraph.[image]

Am I missing anything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you uninstall the Quick Edit module, or view as a non-logged in user?

Comment: Also, are you using Panelizer, Page Manager, or another Panels module?  Can you addd a screencap/markup of what comes after your screenshot above?

Comment: @Jim Disabled Quick Edit module. Still the same. And when I view as non-logged in user the node content area is blank and renders nothing.. I am not using Panels. I have installed "Layout Discovery and Bootstraps Layouts".

Comment: Can you disable Layout Discovery and Bootstraps Layouts and flush the caches?

Comment: If non-logged in user the node content area is blank and renders nothing, you probably need to set permissions to view the bundles, or you also can turn off the Paragraphs Permissions submodule.

Comment: @Jim That did it... Disabled Layout Discovery and field layout. The classes are being wrapped now and works as designated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshots, it looks like it is adding template suggestions back in for the width and color fields. That makes it ignore what we are specifying in the Paragraphs bundle level templates, to print the content without those two fields.

My guess is that comes from the Field Layout module.